# How can I automatically update a table if certain condition is met

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I want to run a trigger, but get a strange error message.

I am using PostgreSQL.

I want to run this update:

```sql
UPDATE tablename
SET status=5
WHERE id=NEW.id 
AND status=4
AND pk!=NEW.pk;
RETURN NEW;
```

... Whenever someone tries to set a status to 4.

So basically I want to have status 4 only once per "id". 
And to ensure that, I want to set all other states that have the same id and have status=4 to status=5.

So I put this into a function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION public.statusfunction()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
UPDATE tablename
SET status=5
WHERE id=NEW.id 
AND status=4
AND pk!=NEW.pk;
RETURN NEW;
END;

$BODY$;
;
```

and execute this functin with a trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER statustrigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON public.tablename
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.statusfunction();
```

But when I test this triggerfunction, and try to update a status to 4 where a dataset with the same status and id already exist, I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE public.tablename 
SET status=5
WHERE id=new.id
AND status=4"
PL/pgSQL function statusfunction() line 3 at SQL statement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include this in the trigger function body:

```
IF pg_trigger_depth() > 1 THEN
   RETURN NEW;
END IF;
```

Your problem is that the `UPDATE`s in the trigger trigger the trigger again, so you get an endless recursion.

Checking for the trigger depth is a simple way to break out of the endless recursion.